# Running Test Runner is not running stepDefination file in cucumber-java junit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, cucumber-java

Expected-- stepDefination code should run.

Eclipse IDE Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)

Below is my POM.xml file configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>API_Projects</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>API_Projects</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 
<properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       
  </properties> 
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>               

                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>

<dependency>

 <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
  
</dependency> 
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>  
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I have run TestRunner.java file using run As>> **JUnit Test** having below code--

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
                 glue={"stepDefinations"},monochrome=true)
public class TestRunner {
 
}
```

---

Below output is coming---

> ```
> ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
> ? Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          ?
> ? Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    ?
> ?                                                                                   ?
> ? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
> ? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
> ? Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    ?
> ? JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) ?
> ?                                                                                   ?
> ? More information at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/environment-variables/      ?
> ?                                                                                   ?
> ? Disable this message with one of the following:                                   ?
> ?                                                                                   ?
> ? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
> ? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
> ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
> ```

Comment: You didn't include your project structure but the few bits you included look wrong. Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: tried this skeleton but still not working

Comment: If you don't carefully describe what you did and what you observed, no one will be able to help you. Best  I can tell you is to throw everything away and start with the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/?lang=java . It works for nearly every one, so it should do for you too.